# How to resolve Uncaught reference error when attempting to call a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have a C# MVC Web application and trying to organize my java script . Since moving the below JavaScript from the view and adding it to a folder  I keep getting a "Uncaught reference error AddArtist" while debugging in FireFox. The scripts worked fine when it was included on the web page.

**I reference jquery and the script as:**

```
<head>
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="/Scripts/AddArtist.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Then here is the script:**

```
(function() {

      $(function() {
        var AddArtist;
        return AddArtist = function() {
          var addDiv, artistVal;
          addDiv = $("#artistname");
          artistVal = $("#artistinput").val();
          $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label></div>").appendTo(addDiv);
          return false;
        };
      });

    }).call(this);
```

****And here is my HTML:****

```
                                    <div id="artist"class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Artists, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                                        <div class="container">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Artists, new { placeholder = "Artist name",@class="form-control", id="artistinput"})  
                                            <img onclick="AddArtist()" id="plusartist" src="\Content\bootstrap\img\plus-button.png" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Artists)
                                        </div>


                                        @*<button id="plusartist" onclick="AddArtist()">Test</button>*@

                                    </div>
                                    <div id="artistname"><label></label></div>
```

Comment: The script is actual compiled from CofeeScript

Comment: The `AddArtist` variable never leaves the scope of the inner function. I don't see how this very script would've worked in a browser -- the method is simply unknown to the outside. Since it is compiled CoffeeScript code, you might wanna show us that code.

Comment: Just a correction. The script in the question was compiled by using cofeescript and wasnt wrapped in 2 fucntions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script the AddArtist function is not exported. I'm not sure what the most stylish way is to create the AddArtist function, but this would probably work:

```
var AddArtist= function() {
      var addDiv, artistVal;
      addDiv = $("#artistname");
      artistVal = $("#artistinput").val();
      $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label> /div>").appendTo(addDiv);
      return false;
    };
```

Comment: This work. thanks. I was using CofeeScripts to create the JavaScript. For some reason it wraps the above scripts in a function

Answer (score 0):

just to add to Adders answer

```
(function() {      
    this.AddArtist = function() {
        alert("called here");
      var addDiv, artistVal;
      addDiv = $("#artistname");
      artistVal = $("#artistinput").val();
      $(" <div id=\"artistname2\"><label>" + artistVal + "</label></div>").appendTo(addDiv);
      return false;
    };
}).call(this);

AddArtist();
```

also [works](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/yKzMx/)